# Why do some @Mock objects not have a mockito interceptor on them?

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I am writing Junits for some legacy code, I realized that when I mock my dependencies using @Mock annotation, some mocked objects seem to have a mockito interceptor associated with them, and some do not. I lack basics in computer programming, any help is appreciated.

```
//Did not work, because of lack of @InkectMocks, 
//see that I create a new object of class to test.
    public class foo {

        ClassInTest classInTest;
        AutoCloseable mocks;

        @Mock
        Animal animal;
        @Mock
        Bike vehicle;

        @Before
        public void init() {
            mocks = openMocks(this);
            classInTest = new ClassInTest();
        }

        @After
        public void teardown() throws Exception {
            mocks.close();
        }

        @Test
        public void dogRidesBikeTest() {
            classInTest.checkIfAnimalRidesVehicle(new Dog(), new Bike());
        }
    }

    public interface Animal {
        public String getName();
        public String doSomething();
    }

    public class Dog implements Animal {
        @Override
        public String getName() {
            return "Dog";
        }
        @Override
        public String doSomething() {
            return "Did something";
        }
    }

    public interface Vehicle {
        public String getName();
        public String doSomething();
    }

    public class Bike implements Vehicle {
        @Override
        public String getName() {
            return "Bike";
        }
        @Override
        public String doSomething() {
            return "Did something";
        }
    }
    
    
    public class ClassInTest {
        public boolean checkIfAnimalRidesVehicle(Animal animal, Vehicle vehicle) {
            vehicle.doSomething();
            remoteMagic(animal, vehicle);
            return false;//dogs don't ride bikes!
        }

        public void remoteMagic(Animal animal, Vehicle vehicle) {
            //magic magic magic
        }
}
```

[screenshot showing that one of the objects created using @Mock has an interceptor and the other does not](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DPSiZ.png)

```
//This is an example of code that works, 
//in line with @Lesiak's answer, the lack of a $MockitoMock$ 
//definition on a mock object should not stop you from being able 
//to stub methods/interact with that mock in any way.
public class FooBarTest {
    @InjectMocks
    FooBar fooBar;
    @Mock
    List<String> mockList;
    @Mock
    CosmosAsyncContainer mockAsyncContainer;
    @Mock
    CosmosContainerResponse mockCosmosContainerResponse;
    AutoCloseable autoCloseable;
    @Before
    public void setup() {
        autoCloseable = openMocks(this);
    }
    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        autoCloseable.close();
    }
    @Test
    public void test() {
        Mono<CosmosContainerResponse> raft = Mono.just(mockCosmosContainerResponse);
        when(mockList.size()).thenReturn(3);
        when(mockAsyncContainer.read()).thenReturn(raft);
        var result = fooBar.helloWorld();
        verify(mockList).size();
        verify(mockAsyncContainer).read();
        assertEquals(result, raft);
    }

}
public class FooBar {
    List<String> goodList;
    CosmosAsyncContainer goodContainer;

    public Mono<CosmosContainerResponse> helloWorld() {
        assertEquals(3, goodList.size());
        Mono<CosmosContainerResponse> raft;
        try {
            raft =  goodContainer.read();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            raft = Mono.empty();
            System.out.println("gotcha!!");
        }
        return raft;
    }
}
```

Is the difference that I am mocking an interface with the mockSomething(this is the one that has an interceptor associated with it), and a class with the mockSomethingElse(this is the one that DOES NOT an interceptor associated with it) objects?

When I put a debug point on the test "dogRidesBikeTest" and observe the objects created in the test context so far, I observe that one of these objects has a mockito interceptor on it, and the other does not.

Should the absence of an interceptor impact method stubbing(I would expect it to), and if yes, how do I work around this.

***edit:***

1. Fixed the error/reason I was unable to stub methods on my mocks in new code sample.
2. The original question "why there is no mockito interceptor on some mock objects" has been answered by @Lesiak
3. The lack of a $MockitoMock$ designation on any mock object should **not** interfere with the way you interact with your mocks given you set your tests/mocks up correctly.

Comment: welcome to stack overflow. Please read the guidlines for adding  a question. Please add the code showing your problem/concern.

Comment: Please don't post images of code, errors, logs, or other text; see [ask]. A [mcve] would be helpful. Also, is this specific to your IDE? If so, which do you use?

Comment: I tried to add some code to the best of my ability, I don't know if this is specific to my IDE, I have not seen this kind of behavior where some @Mock objects were okay to work with(they had an interceptor), and some just look like a POJO generated with default constructors.

Comment: I don't see `mockSomething` or `mockSomethingElse` in your code sample.

Comment: Mockito version? Are you using mockito-core or mockito-inline?

Comment: @tgdavies, mockSomething would align with "animal" and mockSomethingElse would align with "vehicle" objects in the above code.

Comment: @Lesiak I am using mockito-inline

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using [mockito-inline](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/4.9.0/org/mockito/Mockito.html#39), it changes the way the mocks are constructed:

> This alternative mock maker which uses a combination of both Java instrumentation API and sub-classing rather than creating a new class to represent a mock.

[InlineByteBuddyMockMaker javadoc](https://github.com/hustwei/mockito/blob/master/src/main/java/org/mockito/internal/creation/bytebuddy/InlineByteBuddyMockMaker.java#L22) says:

> This mock maker will make a best effort to avoid subclass creation when creating a mock. Otherwise it will use the `org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.SubclassByteBuddyMockMaker` to create the mock class. That means that the following condition is true
>
> ```
> class Foo { }
> assert mock(Foo.class).getClass() == Foo.class;
> ```
>
> unless any of the following conditions is met, in such case the mock maker fall backs to the the creation of a subclass.
>
> - the type to mock is an abstract class.
> - the mock is set to require additional interfaces.
> - the mock is explicitly set to support serialization

In your code:

- Animal is an interface thus subclassing is used
- Bike is a concrete class thus it uses instrumentation

Both mocks are fully functional (stubbing works etc), but the difference can be detected, as you already noticed.

Also, note that you dont pass the mocks to class under test - is that intrntional?

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, I see most of what you said makes sense, in my case I have 2 objects, 

`
assert mock(Foo.class).getClass() == Foo.class;//true
assert mock(Bar.class).getClass() == Bar.class;//false
`

watching the mock Bar object shows something like "Bar$MockitoMock$Dmv40inP", which I believe is what makes method stubbing possible on this mock object, which works fine.

But the mock on "Foo" doesn't have the "MockitoMock"/interceptor on it, which is making stubbing impossible, is there right way to Mocking "Bar" class to be able to stub methods in there?

Comment: @Leisak, thank you very much for your answer, I am much wiser now. A simple "@Mock" should work, and do what I was expecting, what I was lacking, was an "@InjectMocks" on the class to test(your comment that said "You dont use mocks at all - you pass new instances to class under test" triggered the right thought process in me).

I was somehow expecting MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(this) to handle mock injection, including "@InjectMocks" lets me stub the methods in these mock objects that I expect to see in the class in test. Thank you!